# AS3 - add and remove an onenterframe EventListener, with a mouse click

Tags: actionscript-3, event-listener

Trying to add an EventListener, and Remove an EventListener with a mouse click. adding one works, anding it is not working. on buton is gall_mc and off is gall_close_mc

```
gall_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scroller);

function scroller(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    var verticalCenter:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
    var limit:Number = stage.stageHeight - galleryHolder.height;
    var speed:Number = 0.1;
    var scrollY:Number = 0;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollContent);

    function scrollContent(e:Event):void
    {
        scrollY =  -  speed * (mouseY - verticalCenter);
        galleryHolder.y +=  scrollY;
        if (galleryHolder.y>0) { galleryHolder.y= 0;}
        else if (galleryHolder.y< limit) { galleryHolder.y= limit; }
    }
    function eventHandler(event:Event):void
    {
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MouseEvent.CLICK.gall_close_mc);     
    }


}
========
```

Thanks to net.uk.sweet I combined our code and it works!

```
gall_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scroller);

function scroller(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    var verticalCenter:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
    var limit:Number = stage.stageHeight - galleryHolder.height;
    var speed:Number = 0.1;
    var scrollY:Number = 0;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollContent);

    function scrollContent(e:Event):void
    {
        scrollY =  -  speed * (mouseY - verticalCenter);
        galleryHolder.y +=  scrollY;

    }
    gall_close_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeClickHandler);

    function closeClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {

        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollContent);
    }



}
```

Comment: You confused a few things here. First, removeEventListener takes a function as the second parameter, not this: MouseEvent.CLICK.gall_close_mc, which is *nothing*. Second, nesting functions is not a good idea in AS3 unless you really don't know what you're doing, which you don't.  Third, function eventHandler will not get called unless you call it explicitly, which you are not. Rephrase the question and explain what you want to do, possibly attach an image.

Comment: People on here are trying learn and some to help people not insult them!

Comment: Can you point to where I insulted someone? Code still can be improved though. Nesting functions in this way is not a good idea in AS3, scroller is a good candidate for a class/object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gall_close_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeClickHandler);

function closeClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
     // removeEventListener method params are :- 
     // 1. the event name, 2. the handler you assigned to it
     stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, closeClickHandler);
}
```

See [`EventDispatcher` docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html).